Is it possible to create local AEM groups and define permissions up-front, so that during the SSO login AD groups sync-up with permissions in AEM?
I am trying to implement SAML2 based SSO authentication into AEM Author and I would like to explore if there are ways to create the local AEM groups & define permission up-front, bearing the same name as the AD groups that the SSO users are attached to ? The expectation is that when the groups are already existing in AEM,  SSO users can directly start accessing the authorised sections of AEM without waiting to define permissions for the Group claims along with their SAML login.
Tried :

Created "Group A" in AD and made "User-1" as a part of the AD group.
Created same "Group A" in AEM Author and defined permissions to it, even before User login via SSO.

Expecting :

Upon SSO login, the group-claims matches with the existing local group and I expected the user to be added to the existing local AEM group.
However met with an exception in logs, and the group is not listed under the User's membership column in AEM Users console.

Log Error :
org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.basic.DefaultSyncContext Existing authorizable '' is not a group from this IDP ''.
